# Dropdown list selectedchanged event is not firing?

Tags: ajax, event-handling, drop-down-menu

I am using Ajax enabled page and I didn't use any control in this page. Even then `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not firing. I have added items from database, there is no repeatation and also set `AutoPostBack` property="true". I want to add items from database when selecting one item. The selection always shows first element and `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rebinding the drop down list after the postback?

Make sure your page level codebehind has the following conditional:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // bind my drop down list
}
```